# where('videos.created_at', '>', '2020.07.26 14:16:29') not working for left joined table - Eloquent, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, left-join, laravel-relations

everybody.
I have written this code which should return most liked videos posted after the specified date. But the code returns older results than the specified date. I have posted only one video after **2020.07.26** and in spite of this Eloquent returns 8 older videos.

[image][image]

```
$query = Video::select('videos.id',DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT videos.code) AS code'),DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT videos.title) AS title'),DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT videos.created_at) AS createdDate'),DB::raw('count(reactions.id) AS reactCount'))
      ->leftJoin('reactions','reactions.at_video','=','videos.id')
      ->where('reactions.reaction',1)
      ->orWhereNull('reactions.reaction')
      ->where('videos.created_at', '>', '2020.07.26 14:16:29')
      ->groupBy('videos.id')
      ->orderBy('reactCount','DESC')
      ->get();

      dd($query);
```

[image]

Then I found this code on the stockflow where the solution was `whereColumn`. But it did not help me. Laravel showed me another error.

[image]

**whereColumn** example from another post on stackoverflow

```
$query = DB::table('messages')
    ->leftJoin('participants', function ($join) {
        $join->on('messages.thread_id', '=', 'participants.thread_id')
            ->on('messages.user_id', '!=', 'participants.user_id');
    })
    ->select('messages.created_at as message_date', 'participants.last_read as last_read')
    ->whereColumn('messages.created_at', '>', 'participants.last_read')->get();
```

The reason for this is that I group the results. The `videos.created` field returns the value as many times as the likes of the video. To solve this I used `DISTINCT`

```
DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT videos.created_at) AS createdDate')
```

Then I added `createdDate` in the `WHERE()` and unfortunately I got one another error again.

```
->where('createdDate', '>', '2020.07.26 14:16:29')
```

And this is the error I mean. As many time I got it... I almost loved it ;)
[image]

**And...**
I wrote a query code which returns right results and ran in a native php page.
**This is what Laravel should do but it does not...**

```
SELECT videos.id AS id, group_concat(videos.code) AS code, group_concat(videos.title) AS title, group_concat(DISTINCT videos.created_at) AS createdDate, count(reactions.id) AS reactCount
      FROM videos 
      LEFT JOIN reactions ON videos.id = reactions.at_video
      WHERE (reactions.reaction = 1 or reactions.reaction IS NULL)
      AND videos.created_at > '2020.07.27'
      GROUP BY videos.id
      ORDER BY reactCount DESC
```

[image]

I thought I would use custom query code in Laravel as the final solution **but** I have to say **but** one more again.

[image]

```
$videos = DB::select("SELECT videos.id AS id, group_concat(videos.code) AS code, group_concat(videos.title) AS title, group_concat(DISTINCT videos.created_at) AS createdDate, count(reactions.id) AS reactCount
      FROM videos 
      LEFT JOIN reactions ON videos.id = reactions.at_video
      WHERE (reactions.reaction = 1 or reactions.reaction IS NULL)
      AND videos.created_at > '2020.07.27'
      GROUP BY videos.id
      ORDER BY reactCount DESC")->paginate(16);
```

Please someone help me to find a solution. I'm really tired man.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS [mre] [ask] [help]

Comment: All right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found a solution. This is not the best way maybe but it works without any issues yet.

**I added them to my controller**

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
```

**in the function**

```
$query = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT videos.id AS id, group_concat(DISTINCT videos.code) AS code, group_concat(DISTINCT videos.title) AS title, group_concat(DISTINCT videos.created_at) AS createdDate, count(reactions.id) AS reactCount
FROM videos 
LEFT JOIN reactions ON videos.id = reactions.at_video
WHERE (reactions.reaction = 1 or reactions.reaction IS NULL)
AND videos.created_at > '2021.07.27'
GROUP BY videos.id
ORDER BY reactCount DESC"));
    
// Added this three lines of code to make as the results array as a collection
$collection = new Collection($query);
$page = $request->get('page') ? (int)$request->get('page') : 1;
$videos = $collection->forPage($page, 16); 

dd($videos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried using `whereDate()`?

```
->whereDate('videos.created_at', '>', '2020.07.27');
```

Or maybe you should use HasMany Relation to get reaction count.

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-07-27');
```

1. Create HasMany Relation in Video Model

   ```
   public function reactions(){
       $this->hasMany(Reaction::class, 'at_video', 'id');
   }
   ```
2. Create Eloquent Query to fetch record

   ```
   Video::select('id', 'code', 'title')
         ->withCount('reactions')
         ->whereDate('videos.created_at', '>', $date)
         ->get();
   ```

Comment: now it returns all the videos in the database